# WordPress missing in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

The WordPress site data was included in the latest data dump (2011-04-11), but it is not visible in the Data Explorer. Other sites that graduated from beta after WordPress are included (GIS, Electronics). It seems the Data Explorer was last updated around 2011-03-20, which is also after the "graduation date" of WordPress (2011-02-14).

Can someone please add WordPress to the explorer?

Comment: will be added next time I update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update from May 9, 2011 added [WordPress](https://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/queries) to the explorer. Thanks!